# What does the :~> operator do in haskell

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, servant

I was looking through a github project that seems to be a website using haskell and elm. It uses the operator `:~>` [in a type signature in this file](https://github.com/erewok/simpleservantblog/blob/master/src/Types.hs). I can't find a definition for this operator.

What does it do? Why would I use it? What is it called?

Comment: It comes from the [natural-transformation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/natural-transformation) package.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell/info _"What is function foo / operator #$*?"_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a *type operator*. If you look at the top of [the file linked in the OP](https://github.com/erewok/simpleservantblog/blob/fde476d3edf4e7e1172a42626119c0d480410f9c/src/Types.hs), you'll see the following pragma among others:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
```

This means that the language is no longer 'plain' Haskell, but rather Haskell with a few GHC-specific extensions, one of which is the [Type Operators extension](https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/posts/2014-12-08-type-operators.html).

This extension basically just enables you to use infix operators for type definitions, instead of being limited to alphanumerical type names.

As Chris Martin points out in his comment, this particular type operator comes from the [natural-transformation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/natural-transformation/docs/Control-Natural.html) package. It defines the `:~>` operator as a natural transformation from one functor to another.

You could have defined it as a normal `newtype` like this:

```
newtype NT f g x = NT (f x -> g x)
```

Using a type operator, though, makes a function signature like

```
SimpleApp -> SimpleHandler :~> Handler
```

read more like a normal function than

```
SimpleApp -> NT (SimpleHandler Handler)
```

As an example of a natural transformation, consider `listToMaybe` from `Data.Maybe`. This functionality is also sometimes called `safeHead`, but the point is that it's a translation from the *list* (`[]`) functor to the `Maybe` functor.

You can 'promote' that to a natural transformation like this:

```
*Lib Lib Data.Maybe Control.Natural> safeHeadNT = wrapNT listToMaybe
*Lib Lib Data.Maybe Control.Natural> :t safeHeadNT
safeHeadNT :: [] :~> Maybe
```

Notice that the type of `safeHeadNT` is given as `[] :~> Maybe`.

You can unwrap it again if you want to call the function:

```
*Lib Lib Data.Maybe Control.Natural> unwrapNT safeHeadNT [1,2,3]
Just 1
*Lib Lib Data.Maybe Control.Natural> unwrapNT safeHeadNT []
Nothing
```

Another option is to use the package's built-in `#` infix operator:

```
*Lib Lib Data.Maybe Control.Natural> safeHeadNT # []
Nothing
*Lib Lib Data.Maybe Control.Natural> safeHeadNT # [1,2,3]
Just 1
```